# jQuery set textbox - last character missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have 2 textboxes. I want to copy the value of textboxA to textboxB.

I'm currently using `$('#boxB').val($('#boxA').val())`. However, the output is not always correct. For example, if the content of text box A is `abc`, text box B will only end up with `ab`—the last character is always missing. Why?

Comment: that little strip is fine. need to see your code to know what you're doing wrong

Comment: where do you place this code? onclick of a button? or onchange of `#boxA`?

Comment: in a keydown function ` $('#line2').keydown(function (e) {if (e.keyCode == 13) //Enter key
           $('#boxB').val($('#boxA').val()) ;    }); `

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#c").click(function(){
        var valA = $("#textA").val();
        var valB = $("#textB").val();
        valB = valA;
        $("#result").empty().append(valB);
        alert(valB);
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/madcat/tw2ss/

Answer (score 1):

You can see the value of `#boxA` in `keydown` and `keyup` events by using `console.log`:

```
$("#boxA").keydown(function () {
    console.log("down: " + $('#boxA').val())
    $('#boxB').val($('#boxA').val())
})

$("#boxA").keyup(function () {
    console.log("up: " + $('#boxA').val())
    $('#boxB').val($('#boxA').val())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyup, so the event fires after the keypress.

```
$("#myInputBox").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val()
    $("#theSecondBox").val(value)
})
```

**edit:**
[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/LheAW/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `keydown` event, try to use `input` event instead:

```
$('#boxA').on('input', function() {
    $('#boxB').val($('#boxA').val())
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N7mBu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check your Maxlength character of textbox "#boxB" is greater than 3.